# How do I get the senders Public Key using CXF?

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to get the Public Key of the sending party that invoked a method, as a method parameter.
If I have a CXF published SOAP service with asymmetric security, is it somehow possible to tell CXF to make the public key of the invoker available to the method it invokes when calling a web service?

I would like to be able to define the public key as an extra parameter of the method invocation, as such:

```
public interface Webservices{
    public ReturnVal soapMethod(SomeObject input, SomeOtherObject moreInput, PublicKey invokerPubKey)
}
```

The returned pubkey doesn't have to be returned as a PublicKey object, a byte array or really any other format that I can work with would be OK.

I also can't  quite figure out if this could be done by a callback or interceptor, but given that there can be multiple handling threads, I don't see how. Again, advice would be appreciated.

I don't necessarily need the key object itself, getting the alias or any other unique identifier would also be fine, as long as it will lead me to the stored key.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "asymmetric security" ? Is it some kind of WSS or soap level stuff (and which ?) ? Is it pure SSL/TLS level stuff ? I don't think you can easily change the method CXF will invoke (that would mean role your own Invoker interceptor to replace CXF's) but I'm pretty sure you can intercept any `WSS-available` or `HTTPServletRequest` data and make it available to your service implementor through the `MessageContext` (see `@Context` annotation on how to inject the context in your implementor)

Comment: Added working code sample to my answer which is done by me for logging purposes.

Comment: The service does not feature SSL or TLS. The security stems from a WS-Security policy fragment. The fragment defines signature and encryption using public/private keypairs. It is the public key used to decode the signature of the calling party that i want to pass to the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SSL protocol itself should be enough to do that. If you publish your web services using HTTPS then you can configure the server to ask the client for it's certificate ( which will include it's public key ).
For that you can check the following [CXF configuration file](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/wsdl_first_https/src/main/resources/ServerConfig.xml?revision=1540123&view=markup) . As you can see, there is a part that says:

```
<sec:clientAuthentication want="true" required="true"/>
```

This tells the server that it should ask for the client's certificate when a client tries to establish a connection.

Afterwards, you would need to make a bit more configuration:

1. The server should recognize the certificate authority that signed the client's certificate. That you can do adding the CA in the [server's trust store](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_Message_Broker/5.3/html/Security_Guide/files/i379776.html).
2. The client should obviously have somewhere it's certificate. In case it's a java application, you can do it by [adding the certificate in a keystore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step3.html).

You can also check the [complete CXF example](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/wsdl_first_https/).

And now you are ready to get the public key! For that I am going to assume that you are using CXF in a Java EE JAX-WS application.

The first step is to inject the WebServiceContext into your @WebService by adding the following field:

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext webServiceContext;
```

Then you should get the HttpServletRequest form the WebServiceContext:

```
MessageContext messageContext = webServiceContext.getMessageContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)
              messageContext.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
```

Afterwards, you should get the certificate chain from the request:

```
X509Certificate[] certificates = (X509Certificate[])      
       request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

Finally, you should extract the public key from it:

`PublicKey publicKey = certificates[0].getPublicKey();`

(The client's certificate should be the first in the array)

**WS-Security**

In case you are using WS-Security you could do the following:

1. Register an interceptor:

```html
<jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <bean class="my.beloved.MyWSInterceptor"/>
</jaxws:inInterceptors>
```

2. Code the **MyWSInterceptor** interceptor as a subclass of **AbstractSoapInterceptor** and implement the **handleMessage(SoapMessage message)** method:

public class MyWSInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

```
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
    List<WSHandlerResult> results = CastUtils.cast((List<?>) message
        .get(WSHandlerConstants.RECV_RESULTS));
    for (WSHandlerResult wshr : results) {
        for (WSSecurityEngineResult wsser : wshr.getResults()) {
            PublicKey publicKey = wsser
                .get(WSSecurityEngineResult.TAG_PUBLIC_KEY);
        }
    }
}
```

}

For more info about WS-Security configuration in CXF check [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html).

Comment: There is no SSL on the service, only WS-Security asymmetric encryption and signature

Comment: I added WS-Security at the end of the article.

Answer (score 3):

Considering you have configured two way SSL correctly for your web service, 
you can achieve this with an interceptor. But public key will not be passed to the method invocation.

```
public class TestInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

public TestInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.RECEIVE);
}

public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    TLSSessionInfo tlsSessionInfo = (TLSSessionInfo) message
            .get(TLSSessionInfo.class);
    if (tlsSessionInfo != null) {
        Certificate[] peerCerts = tlsSessionInfo.getPeerCertificates();

        for (int i = 0; i < peerCerts.length; i++) {
            X509Certificate x509certificate = (X509Certificate)peerCerts[i];
            x509certificate.getPublicKey(); //DO SOMETHING WITH PUBLIC KEY

            }
    } else {
            System.out.println(" NO x509certificate ");
    }
}
```

}

This way you can get the senders public key with CXF.

Then in your cxf-servlet.xml or other endpoint mapping configure above interceptor as following.

```
 <jaxws:endpoint publish="true" id="helloWorld" implementor="demo.spring.service.HelloWorldImpl" address="/HelloWorld"  >
<jaxws:inInterceptors> <ref bean="srinathSSLInterceptor"/></jaxws:inInterceptors>
</jaxws:endpoint>
<bean id="srinathSSLInterceptor" class="TestInterceptor"/>
```

Comment: There is no SSL on the serviice, only WS-Security asymmetric encryption and signature